# Elasticdump creats one document with 1000 fields when importing a json file in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

There are 1000 records fetch from Database and formatted in to JSON. I need to insert each one as a document in Elasticsearch and `autocomplete_entities` index. The input file looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "x"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "y"
    },
    ...
]
```

I have these settings too

```
PUT _settings
{
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit" : 10000
}
```

and

```
put autocomplete_entities
```

Now when I run this code

> elasticdump --bulk=true --input="PycharmProjects/untitled/v1.json" --output="http://localhost:9200/_doc" --output-index="autocomplete_entities" --type=data --transform="doc._source=Object.assign({},doc)"

It creates one document with 1000 fields such that each fields contains `id`, `title`, as follows

```
"took": 9,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "autocomplete_entities",
            "_type": "autocomplete_entities",
            "_id": "voVp7XQBq56KEuWZ8JuQ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "0": {
                    "id": 37905,
                     "title": "x"
                },
                "1": {
                    "id": 44093,
                    "title": "y"
                } ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I import 1000 records in elasticsearch as 1000 documents ?

Answer (score 0):

can you define mapping for your `autocomplete_entities` index as below

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "data": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And see if its getting indexed properly, this way it would prevent creating the new fields for all your documents, please note that `data` is the [object type of elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) and this is how data can be indexed in above index:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "x"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "y"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I use `Elastic 6.6.1`, it reports error `Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters`

Comment: @MamaD ohh i thought you are on ES 7, anyway please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html which would help you to get rid of this issue

Comment: `put a
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                }              
            }
        }
    }
}`

This will set mapping but it still has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late but `elasticdump` "json" is not *actually* json but [newline-delimited json](http://ndjson.org/) so you should have data formatted like this in your input file:

```
{"id" : 1,"title" : "x"}
{"id" : 2,"title" : "y"}
...
```

Please note lack of commas at the end of each line.